# Duplex printing on windows - Qt5.3

Tags: qt, printing, qt5, qt5.3

From what I have read about duplex printing on windows with Qt I see is still not possible, but exists a workaround or another way to make available duplex printing on windows?

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprinter.html#duplex `Currently this option is only supported on X11.`

Comment: And that's why I said that I want to know if exists a workaround or another way...

Comment: IMO if user will configure printer using system dialog to configure printer it should work.

Comment: Yeah, I would expect that too. Printer driver settings override application settings like all the time. Except when they don't, but these (rare) cases seem to be driver bugs to me.